# piping output from programs that do not output to STDOUT

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, named-pipes

Say I have a program that outputs to a file which is provided by an (required) argument:

```
./foo -o bar.txt
```

Is there any way to trick it into outputting to a pipe? This just outputs to a file named `-`.

```
./foo -o - | less
```

Comment: `-` as an alias for standard output (or standard input) is a convention that may or may not be respected by your applications. It does not have any special meaning in the shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `/dev/stdout` as the file name:

```
./foo -o /dev/stdout | less
```

Answer (score 0):

This will feed the contents of bar.txt to *filter* as the file grows:

```
tail -f bar.txt | filter
```

Comment: If it's run from another terminal or the original process is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

other solution, create a named pipe:

```
mkfifo /tmp/myfifo; ./foo -o /tmp/myfifo
</tmp/myfifo cat -
```